# Обнуление массива в Си

Tags: c++, c

Как правильно обнулить массив? Речь о любых типах массива, будь то символьный, целочисленный, динамический и т.п Если способов несколько то желательно написать как можно больше.

Способ, который изучен мною выглядит как - то так:

```
char str[100] = {0};
```

Но я не знаю является ли такой метод обнуления верным, с технической точки зрения и с точки зрения процедурного программирования и объектно-ориентированного программирования.

Comment: В заголовке сказано "Си". Тэги стоят [C] и [C++]. Так все-таки: по какому языку вопрос?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вам нужно обнуление при объявлении - да, это совершенно верный способ. Для глобального массива не нужно и это.

Если нужно обнулить уже имеющийся массив - берите для этого `memset`. Например,

```
char * str = malloc(100);
memset(str,0,100);
```

Но динамический массив можно обнулять и сразу - если выделять `calloc`:

```
char * str = calloc(100,1);
```

P.S. Таких способо всколько угодно. Я написал в основном те, которые С. Но можно и так

```
char str[100];
std::fill(&str[0],&str[100],0);
```

или

```
char str[100];
std::generate(&str[0],&str[100],[](){return 0;});
```

и еще сотней других способов.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Почему не варианты? Можно как угодно, хоть через стандартную библиотеку.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но fill (как и fill_n) работает с типом INT, поэтому запись типа:
char str[100];
std::fill(&str[0],&str[100],0);
- некорректна, так как тип INT обычно занимает 4 байта и таким образом вы обнулите ещё 3 байта сверх нужного.